# How to use Padding 'ISO10126' for AES Encryption in Flutter?

Tags: android, flutter, encryption, aes, padding

I am using `encrypt: ^4.1.0` `flutter library` for AES Encryption.

Here is my code:

```
import 'package:encrypt/encrypt.dart';

class AesEncryption {
  encryption() {
  final plainText =
        '{"Username":"01717222787",RefId":"5c6de3e4-ea65-49be-bdc5-7eba0128fefc"}';
    final key = Key.fromUtf8('32 length code ...');
    final iv = IV.fromUtf8('16 lenght code...');

    final encrypter = Encrypter(AES(key, mode: AESMode.cbc));

    final encrypted = encrypter.encrypt(plainText, iv: iv);
    final decrypted = encrypter.decrypt(encrypted, iv: iv);

    print(decrypted);
    print(encrypted.base64);
  }
}
```

Flutter Library said that, No/Zero padding is supported but `encrypter = Encrypter(AES(key, mode: AESMode.cbc, padding: null))` doesn't work.

I want to use `encrypter = Encrypter(AES(key, mode: AESMode.cbc, padding: 'ISO10126'))` which is already used in my server code. I found `padding:'ISO7816-4'` this, but the encrypted data is different from server.

Is there any way to use `padding: 'ISO10126'` for AES Encryption in `AES.CBC` mode?

Comment: [_encrypt_](https://github.com/leocavalcante/encrypt/blob/main/README.md) is essentially a wrapper around a part of the [_PointyCastle_](https://github.com/bcgit/pc-dart#pointy-castle) functionality that doesn't seem to provide ISO 10126 (btw withdrawn, 2007) (see section _Paddings_). If you don't find a library that supports this padding and you need it for compatibility reasons, you could implement it yourself (which is not very difficult, see [here](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Padding_(cryptography)#ISO_10126)). For this you would have to disable the implicit padding with `padding: null`.

Comment: @Topaco thanks for your answer. I already tried [PointyCastel](https://pub.dev/packages/pointycastle) and padding `ISO7816-4`. But the problem is, in server side `ISO10126` is implemented. So the encrypted and decrypted value doesn't match.

Comment: Yes, _PointyCastle_ (and the _encrypt_ package based on it) don't seem to support ISO 10126 (see the links in my first comment). So my suggestion is (if you can't find any other library that supports ISO 10126) to disable the implicit padding and implement ISO 10126 by yourself.

Comment: Possibly [_Steel Crypt_](https://pub.dev/packages/steel_crypt/versions/1.7.1+1) is an option.

Answer (score 0):

Flutter dosen't support Padding 'ISO10126' for AES Encryption. Instead, I found the solution where we can get the expected result by using [encrypt: ^4.1.0](https://pub.dev/packages/encrypt). We also change the padding 'ISO10126' to 'PKCS7' in both end. So here is the final code snippet:

> ```
> import 'package:encrypt/encrypt.dart'; 
>
> class AesEncryption {   
>      
> String encryption(String plainText) {
>      
>      final key = Key.fromBase64(ENCRYPTION_KEY);
>      final iv = IV.fromBase64(ENCRYPTION_IV);
>
>      final encrypter = Encrypter(AES(key, mode: AESMode.cbc, padding: 'PKCS7'));
>      final encrypted = encrypter.encrypt(plainText, iv: iv);
>
>  return encrypted.base64;   
> }
>
> String decryption(String plainText) {
>
>    final key = Key.fromBase64(ENCRYPTION_KEY);
>    final iv = IV.fromBase64(ENCRYPTION_IV);
>
>    final encrypter = Encrypter(AES(key, mode: AESMode.cbc, padding: 'PKCS7'));
>    final decrypted = encrypter.decrypt(Encrypted.from64(plainText), iv: iv);
>
>   return decrypted;   
>  } 
> }
> ```